# SWI Prolog multiple knowledge bases

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Im my application I have a number of agents, each with his own knowledge base.
My original idea was having multiple engine instances, but swi prolog allows at most one instance.
The other way is adding an additional term representing the agent id to each fact and rule, but it seems very cumbersome.

For example, instead of:

```
position(10, 20).
do(action(X)):-...
```

I would have to write everywhere:

```
position(agent0, 10, 20).
do(Agent, action(X)):-...
```

Because I will update one agent at a time, even saving and restoring everything each time may be ok, even if I don't know how to do that. Or using modules?
What would be a good way to separate the different knowledge bases?

Comment: see [Logtalk](http://logtalk.org/)

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into it now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your suggestion of adding an atomic ID to your facts to identify the agent it corresponds to is a nice one, but agree this could be cumbersome to add to your code in  retrospect.

Here are some other suggestions, roughly in order of my preference...

1. Use the [recorded database](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.13%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/db.html%27%29%29). With this, you can actually record facts with atomic keys, so presumably, you could use [`recorda/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.13%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/db.html%27%29%29) and like predicates to record facts for each agent separately with agent IDs, then use [`recorded/2,3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.13%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/db.html%27%29%29) to retrieve them. Nearly precisely what you want.
2. Use [modules](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%281,%275%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/modules.html%27%29%29). Presumably you could simply create new module names for each agent, thus separating the facts for each, much like the way namespaces are used. For example, asserting `agent0:position(10,20)`.
3. Keep explicit track of the facts you assert for each agent using [`assert/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=assert/2) which returns clause references. By keeping a list of references which identify all facts asserted for a particular agent, you can quickly retract them using [`erase/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=erase/1). Be aware that using clause references with a combination of [`clause/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=clause/3) to retrieve clauses via their reference together with [`retract/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=retract/1) could potentially retract like-clauses belonging to other agents.
4. Depending on how your program is structured, you could simply pass around a large data structure with all the facts for each agent in a list like: `[agent0-[fact1(..), fact2(..), ...], agent1-[...], ...]` and update this term as you go. Note that this isn't as efficient as using the database itself, as it would require a lot of linear scans for particular facts; hash-lookups can't be used.

Comment: about modules: the problem is that rules that need (for instance) position/2 *must* qualify it with agent0: i.e. you need to pass the module identifier to each such rule, exactly that the OP complains. I'd really like to see a viable workaround for this, since I wrote (25 years ago!) an object oriented Prolog interpreter with such features available....

Comment: Thank you both for the alternatives. Logtalk looks like a very powerful tool, for someone like me that uses prolog for the first time having some object oriented elements is reassuring. I wasn't aware either of the recorded database, which seems very easy and fast to use.